# Search through two 3 column numpy array and find where meets criteria in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, loops

I have two numpy array like

```
Population A

Score A Score B Answer
  1       0.3      1    
  0       0.5      0
  1       0.6      1     
  0       0.7      1
  1       0.9      1

Population B

Score A Score B Answer
  1       0.3      1    
  0       0.5      0
  1       0.6      1     
  1       0.7      1
  0       0.9      1

 Sample Results are
 ScoreB     Ratio 
  0.3        1
  0.5        1
  0.6        1
  0.7        1
```

I have to find score/value of score B  in each population, any value above that value becomes 1 else 0, for example if you pick 0.5 in population A then first value is 0 rest are 1, similarly if you pick 0.6 in population B for example then first two value are 0 rest are 1.

I have to do this iteratively/ algorithmic possibly in while loop I guess  and without creating or replacing scoreB such that

```
Ratio = (counts(scoreA=1&scoreb=1&Answer=1) in population A/ counts(scoreA=1&scoreb=1&Answer=1) in population B) == 1
```

Note: Score B is sorted so not to worry about that

Comment: This sounds like `np.where()` but your description isn't quite clear. Perhaps a sample of your desired output would help.

Comment: Added see in this case only 0.3,0.5,0.6 and 0.7 yield you same ratio as soon as you go 0.9 the criteria of ratio wont match

Comment: ratio is strange: for 0.9, count in population B is 0. Do you divide by zero? If count in pop B is less than count in pop A, do you get a ratio greater than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [logical_and](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) or simply the `*` operator on numpy array which gives element wise multiplication

```
import numpy as np
def count_match (v, A, B, C):

  cond = np.logical_and(A == 1, B >= v)
  cond = np.logical_and(cond, C == 1)
  # alternatively, use an element wise product:
  cond = (A == 1) * (B >= v) * (C == 1)

  # counting the number of 1
  count = np.sum(cond)
  return count

A_a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
B_a = np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9])
C_a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1])

A_b = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
B_b = np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9])
C_b = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
for v in [0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9]:
  print(v, count_match(v, A_a, B_a, C_a) / count_match(v, A_b, B_b, C_b)) # divides by zero brr
```

note btw that for popA and popB, the condition on array A and C do not change, so you may precompute them already (I doubt that it changes time that much)

```
def count_match2(v, pre_cond, B):
  return np.sum(pre_cond * (B >= v))

for v in [0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9]:
  print(v, count_match2(v, (A_a == 1) * (C_a == 1), B_a) / count_match2(v, (A_b == 1) * (C_b == 1), B_b)) # divides by zero brr
```